# Scala suffix notation is compiling

Tags: scala, compilation, coding-style

The Scala [style guide](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html#suffix_notation) says this about suffix notation:

> This style is unsafe, and should not be used. Since semicolons are
>   optional, the compiler will attempt to treat it as an infix method if
>   it can, potentially taking a term from the next line.
>
> ```
> names toList
> val answer = 42        // will not compile!
> ```
>
> This may
>   result in unexpected compile errors at best, and happily compiled
>   faulty code at worst. Although the syntax is used by some DSLs, it
>   should be considered deprecated, and avoided.

(The code comment is part of the original material.)

I tried to demonstate this to someone.

**test.scala**

```
val names = List(1, 2, 3)
names toList
val answer = 42         // will compile!
```

But it compiled and ran fine

```
$ scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.9.1 -- Copyright 2002-2011, LAMP/EPFL
$ scala test.scala
```

What's wrong with my example?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a better example:

```
List(1, 2, 3) toList
42
```

is parsed as

```
List(1, 2, 3).toList(42)
```

and throws an exception (after inserting `apply`) instead of returning `42`.

Presumably in the style guide example `val` prevents misinterpretation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's help you to find answer:

This may result in unexpected compile errors at best, and happily compiled faulty code at worst. Although the syntax is used by some DSLs, it should be considered deprecated, and avoided.

As of Scala 2.10, using suffix operator notation will result in a compiler warning.

Warning appears on scala >= 2.10, not previous versions.

Comment: I believe you misread. I was not interested in the compiler warning but rather the failure to compile (`// will not compile!`)